# Best way to find vertical contours in a colored image

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, edge-detection

I want to detect only the vertical contours on an image like this:

[image]

The standard method with canny detector gives back a poor result. (i prefer openCV API, but any idea would be helpful)

Comment: you can try sobel or laplace edge detector then threshold it and pass to hough

Answer (score 0):

You can use hough line detection to detect vertical lines

Comment: The Hough works on detected edges, not on the image directly. http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html

Answer (score 0):

You should apply a horizontal filtering (e.g. Sobel – cvSobel() ), which will detect only the vertical edges.